# Save from Excel 2013 into 2010 format

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2013

To my utter surprise, when saving in Excel 2013, then re-open in Excel 2010, you can't edit any of the numbers 'because this document was created in a newer version of excel'.

There is no option in the 'save as...' dialog.

Can anyone get Excel 2013 saved files to work on Excel 2010 (including pivot tables)?

Comment: Unless you use the Excel 2003 format what you want is NOT possible( at this time).

Answer (score 1):

Looks this is an issue with the new Pivot Table Model in Excel 2013. See [Version compatibility between PowerPivot Data Models in Excel 2010 and Excel 2013](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/version-compatibility-between-powerpivot-data-models-in-excel-2010-and-excel-2013-HA103929426.aspx). Normally Microsoft is very good about maintaining compatibility between recent versions. Looks becuase  of the functionality for Pivot tables they had to break it.

Comment: Even Word 2010 and Word 2013 have a problem.  It has everything to do with using the 1.2 revision of the open standard that is used.  Excel 2013 can open 1.1 documents but cannot save them.  This means we have to wait until Word 2010 is updated with a compatability pack to support 1.2.  This issue is well documented on tech articles.

Comment: Sorry, MSFT has been excellent at allowing _reading_ old documents, but _horrible_ at writing old formats (it isn't too easy to shoehorn new functionality into the old format; besides, it doesn't get paid for old versions people can still continue using...).